# ruby arrays count of most frequent element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, integer

I'm trying to figure out how to find a count of the most frequent element in an array of integers. I can think of a few methods that might be helpful but when I get to writing an expression inside the block I get complete lost on how to compare an element with the next and previous element. Any ideas? All help is really really appreciated!!!

Comment: That this question is a duplicate is hardly surprising. It's not clear, however, which question it's a dup of. My reading of the question is that the max count is to be returned ("...how to find a count of the most frequent element in an array..."). (See @Tadman's comment on my answer.) The source of "This question already has an answer here:" asks for the element whose count is greatest. Granted, it's a very short step from the answer to that question to obtaining the max count, but there may be better ways if only the max count is desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy was is to determine all the unique values, convert each to its count in the array, then determine the largest count.

```
def max_count(arr)
  arr.uniq.map { |n| arr.count(n) }.max
end
```

For example:

```
arr = [1,2,4,3,2,6,3,4,2]
max_count(arr)
  #=> 3
```

There are three steps:

```
a = arr.uniq
  #=> [1, 2, 4, 3, 6] 
b = a.map { |n| arr.count(n) }
  #=> [1, 3, 2, 2, 1] 
b.max
  #=> 3
```

A somewhat more efficient way (because the elements of `arr` are enumerated only once) is to use a counting hash:

```
def max_count(arr)
  arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }.values.max
end

max_count(arr)
  #=> 3
```

We have:

```
a = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }
  #=> {1=>1, 2=>3, 4=>2, 3=>2, 6=>1} 
b = a.values
  #=> [1, 3, 2, 2, 1] 
b.max
  #=> 3
```

See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) for an explanation of `Hash.new(0)`. Briefly, if `h = Hash.new(0)` and `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` will return the default value, which here is zero. `h[k] += 1` expands to `h[k] = h[k] + 1`, so if `h` does not have a key `k`, this becomes `h[k] = 0 + 1`. On the other hand, if, say, `h[k] => 2`, then `h[k] = h[k] + 1 #=> h[k] = 3 + 1`.

Comment: Don't forget [`max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

Comment: @tadman, I considered `max_by`, but it's the max count, not the element having the max count, that is wanted. If I used `max_by` I'd need to recompute the count for that element, which did not appeal.

Comment: That's one interpretation of the question, it's true. I read it the other way of wanting the most frequent element *based on* count.

Comment: Thanks Cary! Very informative with your solution. Really helped my understanding.